# Is it possible to use file creation code inside actionPerformed class?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am new to JAVA. I am trying to make gui for login and registration form. at the moment, I am focusing on registration. What I want is to save data created inside actionPerformed class  into text form. For this, I put the file creation code inside actionPerformed class

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == sub) {
        if (term.isSelected()) {
            String data1;
            String data
                = "Name : "
                  + tname.getText() + "\n"
                  + "Mobile : "
                  + tmno.getText() + "\n";
            if (male.isSelected())
                data1 = "Gender : Male"
                        + "\n";
            else
                data1 = "Gender : Female"
                        + "\n";
            String data2
                = "DOB : "
                  + (String)date.getSelectedItem()
                  + "/" + (String)month.getSelectedItem()
                  + "/" + (String)year.getSelectedItem()
                  + "\n";

            String data3 = "Address : " + tadd.getText();
            tout.setText(data + data1 + data2 + data3);
            tout.setEditable(false);
            res.setText("Registration Successfully..");
            String txt_path = "C:\\FMP\\Users.txt";
            File file = new File(txt_path);
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            filewriter.write(data + data1 + data2 + data3);
            filewriter.flush();
            filewriter.close();
        }
        else {
            tout.setText("");
            resadd.setText("");
            res.setText("Please accept the"
                        + " terms & conditions..");
        }
    }
```

I run this code, and I got nothing by clicking sub(which is button), it's supposed to be saved in .txt (C:\FMP\Users.txt)). the data is shown on Text, but not saved.

Comment: Is this Java Swing? If so, you could tag it accordingly, so as to attract more viewers. Other than that, can you post a [mre]? Where are you catching the `IOException`s?

Comment: @gthanop thank you for only attention to my post. Fortunately,i solved my question by my own! thank you!